# Suppressing a void static method and a static method in same class with PowerMock

Tags: java, junit, mocking, powermock

I'm currently trying to do some unit testing on a some legacy code using PowerMock 1.4.10 and there is a method that I'm trying to test that has both static void calls and static non-void calls.  Is there a way to mock the static non-void calls while suppressing the static void call?

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassUnderTest.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        MemberModifier.suppress(StaticClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("logRandom"));

        PowerMock.mockStatic(StaticClass.class);
        expect(StaticClass.isLogOn()).andReturn(true);
        PowerMock.replay(StaticClass.class);

        ClassUnderTest test = new ClassUnderTest();
        test.methodToTest();

        assertTrue(test.tested);

        PowerMock.verify(StaticClass.class);
    }
}


public class ClassUnderTest {
    public boolean tested = false;

    public void methodToTest() {
        if (StaticClass.isLogOn()) {
            StaticClass.logRandom();
        }
    }

}

public class StaticClass {

    public static void logRandom() {
        System.out.println("Do something");
    }

    public static boolean isLogOn() {
        return (Math.random() > .5);
    }
}
```

But when I try to do this, I get the following stackTrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControlForLastCall(EasyMock.java:521)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.expect(EasyMock.java:499)
    at TestClass.test(TestClass.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:307)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:102)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Does anyone have any ideas for how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had success testing statics with a combination of PowerMock and Mockito called PowerMockito.  You would mock your static call with the `PowerMockito.mockStatic` instead of the `PowerMock` version.  Once that is done, you can call `Mockito.when` to handle the call.

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticClass.class);
Mockito.when(StaticClass.isLogOn()).thenReturn(true);
```

When the test runs, when it reaches test execution of `if (StaticClass.isLogOn()) {`, the mocking should step in and return true, which kicks into the logic for calling the `logRandom`.  From here, you can try using `spy` to let it call the actual code, or you can mock that `logRandom` call as needed.  You can find more info on mocking using `spy` on the [PowerMocktio Page](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) under `Partial Mocking`.